# How to convert and save dynamic rows to dynamic columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have this table called `events`, Where I am saving every event that occurs on site.
[Fiddle and code which I tried](https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql80/49d8a2f901a1a02cabf60352b6944d1f/)

```
+====+==========+=========+===============+=========+=====================+
| id | type     | user_id | website       | data    | created_at          |
+====+==========+=========+===============+=========+=====================+
| 1  | pageview | 1       | example.com   | /       | 2022-02-16 22:00:00 |
+----+----------+---------+---------------+---------+---------------------+
| 2  | pageview | 2       | example.com   | /path   | 2022-02-16 22:00:00 |
+----+----------+---------+---------------+---------+---------------------+
| 3  | purchase | 3       | example.com   | 2222    | 2022-02-16 22:00:00 |
+----+----------+---------+---------------+---------+---------------------+
| 4  | view     | 3       | example.com   | product | 2022-02-16 22:00:00 |
+----+----------+---------+---------------+---------+---------------------+
| 5  | click    | 3       | example.com   | card    | 2022-02-16 22:00:00 |
+----+----------+---------+---------------+---------+---------------------+
| 6  | pageview | 4       | site.com      | /       | 2022-02-16 22:00:00 |
+----+----------+---------+---------------+---------+---------------------+
| 7  | click    | 4       | site.com      | product | 2022-02-16 22:00:00 |
+----+----------+---------+---------------+---------+---------------------+
| 8  | custom   | 5       | example1.com  | test    | 2022-02-16 22:00:00 |
+----+----------+---------+---------------+---------+---------------------+
| 9  | custom2  | 6       | google.com    | test    | 2022-02-16 22:00:00 |
+----+----------+---------+---------------+---------+---------------------+
| 10 | custom3  | 5       | example11.com | test    | 2022-02-16 22:00:00 |
+----+----------+---------+---------------+---------+---------------------+
```

And I have dynamic table on the front side, where I want to have dynamic columns, something like this.

```
+==========+=========+==========+=========+=========+=========+=========+=========+
| name     | ...     | event 1  | event 2 | event 3 | event 4 | event 5 | ...     |
+==========+=========+==========+=========+=========+=========+=========+=========+
| test     | ...     | 5        | 50      | 5       | 76      | 23      | ...     |
+----------+---------+----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| test2    | ...     | 1        | 78      | 25      | 88      | 54      | ...     |
+----------+---------+----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Where `event1`, `event2` ... are dynamic columns from `events.type` column.

I am looking the best way to organize and aggregate data from `events` table.

I have already written query to convert rows to columns and display data the way I want, But the problem is to save this aggregated data in a way that I can filter it later.

- `type` column in `events` table can contain thousands of `DISTINCT` values
- I have to aggregate data per user. For example: User 1 may only have `pageview`, `purchase` ... events, User 2 may have `purchase`, `testevent1` ... events, So thay will have different columns on the front side.

Any recommendations about how to aggregate `events` data and save it in another table, where I can run queries different queries later?

[Fiddle and code which I tried](https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql80/49d8a2f901a1a02cabf60352b6944d1f/)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, you cannot make a table that has different columns on each row. There is no such thing as "dynamic columns".

One of the fundamental facts that makes relational databases work is that a table has a heading which names the columns and data types, followed by a set of rows, where each row in a table has exactly the same columns as the heading for that table.

So the best you could do is make a table that has one column for each event type, even if the event type is not usable by some users. The value in that column could be NULL, to signify that it's not relevant to that user.

In an SQL SELECT query, you must specify all the columns in the query. The columns must be fixed in the query, before the query is parsed and before it begins executing. There's no way to make a query that adds columns dynamically as it examines data during the query execution.

You therefore have a type of pivot query:

```
SELECT user_id,
 COUNT(CASE type WHEN 'pageview' THEN 1 END) AS `pageview`,
 COUNT(CASE type WHEN 'purchase' THEN 1 END) AS `purchase`,
 COUNT(CASE type WHEN 'view' THEN 1 END) AS `view`,
 COUNT(CASE type WHEN 'click' THEN 1 END) AS `click`,
 ...more column expressions until you account for all possible types... 
FROM events
GROUP BY user_id;
```

Before you can write this query, you must know all the possible event types. You may do this with another query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT type FROM events;
```